# How to apply some operation to each element of a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple like `(p1, p2)` (for example (5,3) or (2,1))
I want to apply the same operation *to each element* of the tuple. (Incidentally this operation will give *for each* element another tuple, so I will have a tuple of tuples but this is not a necessary condition)

First I thought something like

```
for element in (3,2):
    res=function(element)
```

but first, this doesn't seem a elegant solution and two, I would still have to form a tuple from each `res` to get a `(function(3),function(2))` solution

How can I apply a function (with several arguments) to each element of the tuple once and get a tuple of returned values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, `map` should to the job as well:

```
tuple(map(func, tpl))
```

where `func` is a one-argument function you defined.

Now, if you have a function *with several arguments* you would like to apply to each element, like:

```
def func(x, y, z): return x*y+z
```

I assume that 2 elements (let's take y and z) are fixed, while x will be determined by the value in the tuple.
There are two approaches in my view:

- Either you define a new function with 2 fixed arguments and `map`:

  ```
  def func1(x): return func(x, 3, 2)
  tuple(map(func1, tpl))
  ```
- Or map as follows (I think it is less elegant, but it is a matter of tastes, maybe):

  ```
  tuple(map(lambda x: func(x, 3, 2), tpl))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses a list comprehension:

```py
def add_one(x):
    return x + 1

tpl = (5, 3)
output = tuple([add_one(x) for x in tpl])
print(output)  # (6, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using the generator comprehension then convert it to tuple:

```
>>> data = (3, 5, 7, 9)
>>> tuple((function(x) for x in data))
```